# Spring LdapAuthentication and Load roles from local database

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

I have Spring Security configured to authenticate against LDAP server.

```
<security:authentication-manager >
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0}" />

</security:authentication-manager>
```

After authentication I want to load roles from local database for the same user. How can I load local database roles using "ldap-authentication-provider"?

If I add the second authentication provider as below:

```
<security:authentication-manager >
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0}" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

`daoAuthenticationProvider` added, but Spring does not use the second provider when first auth provider authenticates the user. Only if the first auth provider fails to authenticate it goes next in the list.

So basically look like we have to customize

```
<security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0}" />
```

to load ROLEs from local database.

Any suggestions? How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 5):

An authentication provider must deliver a fully populated authentication token on successfull authentication, so it's not possible to use one provider to check the user's credentials, and another one to assign authorities (roles) to it.

You can however customize an ldap auth provider to fetch user roles from database instead of the default behaviour (searching for the user's groups in ldap). The `LdapAuthenticationProvider` has two strategies injected: one that performs the authentication itself (`LdapAuthenticator`), and another one that fetches the user's authorities (`LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`). You can achieve your requirements if you supply an `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` implementation that loads roles from database. In case you already have a `UserDetailsService` working against the database, you can easily integrate that by wrapping it in a `UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` and injecting it in the `LdapAuthenticationProvider`.

Since this configuration is rather uncommon, the security xml namespace doesn't provide tags/attributes to set it up, but the raw bean config isn't too complicated. Here is the outline:

1) I suppose you have an `ldap-server` somewhere in your config. It's important to assign and `id` to it, which will allow us to reference it later.

```
<security:ldap-server url="..." id="ldapServer" .../>
```

2) From the `authentication-manager` section, you will only refer to the customized provider:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customLdapAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

3) Now, the essential part:

```
<bean id="customLdapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="ldapServer"/>
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg name="userService" ref="userService"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The `authenticator` is basically the same as the one that would be created by the namespace config. (Note the `contextSource` attribute referencing the ldap server.)

The `authoritiesPopulator` is a simple wrapper around your `userService` implementation which is supposed to be defined somewhere in your config.

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to add userId to the User. map empId from ldap to userId attribute in User object.

Comment: This question seems to be unrelated to the original one. It's probably better if you reformulate it and post as a new question, because at the moment only I can see it (practically), while other users could be able to give you better answers. Anyway, mapping user attributes from ldap to DB is absolutely possible, but it's not something you would (could) do with Spring Security.