# parse memberOf attribute to get group in spring security3

Tags: string, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I am using spring security 3.1.3 for authentication via LDAP, code is working fine.Now, I want to get group of authenticated user. I've developed my custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator in my application.Below is my code.

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = null;
        Object[] objects = userData.getObjectAttributes("memberOf");
        for(Object object: objects){
            System.out.println((String)object + "---------"+object.getClass());
        }
}


console output : CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=in
```

I don't want to perform string parsing, Is there any inbuilt function so that I can get group of authenticated user in my above implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [`ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) instead of a customized `LdapAuthenticationProvider`? It's tailor made to deal with AD, e.g. the mapping from group memberships to authorities is already implemented in its [`loadUserAuthorities()`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L144-L164) method.

Refer to [19.5. Active Directory Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ldap.html#ldap-active-directory) in the reference docs for more details.

Comment: no, did I do something wrong? one more thing, I want to populate authority from database instead of LDAP. The whole scenario is authenticate user from LDAP and get corresponding group of user and after that populate authority from database.

Comment: It would probably be easier to configure an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` if you want to do auth against AD, but you can use a plain `LdapAuthenticationProvider` as well of course. As you can see, the above linked implementation of `loadUserAuthorities()` simply takes the value of the last segment of the group's DN (`Administrators`). You can do the same in your custom `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` and fetch whatever info you need from the DB based on that.

Comment: how to do that?would you please explain bit more using custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what to explain more? You can get the group memberships with some code similar to the implementation of `loadUserAuthorities()`. Then fetch your data based on the groups in whatever way you normally talk to your DB. If you need help on how to wire things up in xml config, try to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481814/1276804) I gave to a similar question.

Comment: I am looking inbuilt function to parse string object returned from below code.
Object[] objects = userData.getObjectAttributes("memberOf");
Is there any inbuilt function?
I am trying to parsing below String output so that I can get Group of authenticated user
CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=in.

Comment: As already said and linked, the `loadUserAuthorities()` method extracts the group's name this way: `new SimpleGrantedAuthority(new DistinguishedName(group).removeLast().getValue())`, where `group` is the group DN (like '"CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=in"'). This is not available as an independent method though, so you'll have to copy it, or parse the string another way you prefer.

Comment: I don't know, your answer is correct or not.But, it helped me alot.So, my 50 points goes to you.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear about what you really want to do. I'm assuming based on whatever has been discussed so far that you want to extract (i.e., parse out) the name of the group from the DN you get. In your example, you want to extract the "CN=Administrators" RDN from "CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=in" ??! Again, this is my assumption based on what I read and I understood (sort of).

If you don't want to do the parsing, you can perhaps use JNDI's CompoundnName class with your own syntax definition, but I'm not sure if using this class will give you any dramatic advantage over your own string parsing, which actually should not be complicated. But, here's how you can use CompoundName:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.CompoundName;

public class NameTestSimple {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Properties syntax = new Properties();
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.direction", "left_to_right");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.separator", ",");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.ignorecase", "true");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.escape", "\\");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.trimblanks", "true");
        // syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.separator.ava", ",");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.separator.typeval", "=");
        syntax.setProperty("jndi.syntax.beginquote", "\"");

        String name = "CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=in";

        CompoundName cn = new CompoundName(name, syntax);

        System.out.println("DN: " + cn);

        System.out.println("\nCompoundName details:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < cn.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + i + " --> " + cn.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Even with this, you will still need to parse the individual RDNs to get the attribute values (e.g., parse "CN=Administrators" to extract the value of 'Administrators').

Comment: u'r assumption is what I wanted.But, zagyi's last comment solved my problem. i.e 
new DistinguishedName(group).removeLast().getValue();
This is behaving perfectly upto my knowledge. can it be break in any case?