# How to use Spring Ldap Authentication

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

In my current project, I have to implement LDAP authentication. 
I am using JSF 2.2, primefaces and Spring 4.0 and spring-ldap-core 1.3.2 and spring-security-ldap-3.2.0. Below are the work till now I have done to achieve:

Spring-Ldap.xml

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
 <property name="url" value="ldap://mumcXXXXXXX" />
 <property name="base" value="dc=ad,dc=XXX,dc=com"/>
 <property name="userDn" value="XXXX@ad.XXX.com" />
 <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapContact"
    class="com.csap.research.LDAPContactDAO">
    <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
</bean>
```

My LdapContactDao

```
public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true); 
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("userPrincipalName", username+"@ad.cXXX.com"));
        return ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.toString(), password);
}
```

Here username and password are coming from Login screen as inputs. My problem is its very hardcoded. I dont want to hardcode **username** and **password** in **Spring-Ldap.xml** , So there was a suggestion to use Spring-security-Ldap here [Spring LdapAuthentication and Load roles from local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469314/spring-ldapauthentication-and-load-roles-from-local-database) but I was unable to understand it.

My question was how I can achieve dynamic integration of Ldap with spring and corse JSF i am using as a front-end controller.
Any help would be great.

Comment: what do you mean with dynamic integration? you need users to login with LDAP authentication or something more?

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto dynamic in the sense ,I have to put manager credential hardcoded in the Spring-Ldap.xml file to connect with ldap-server. I want to connect dynamically, i dont want to use hardcoded credentials in spring-ldap.xml.

Comment: api is deaprecated

Answer (score 6):

I found these article helpful for setting up login form with spring security, however, they do not use jsf:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/
  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

and found this article helpful for using ldap as authentication provider, it does not use ldapTemplate, but uses the spring-security configurations (spring-security.xml in the article)

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is not what i was looking for,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am using LDAP for authentication:

1. Import Maven dependencies

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Write your implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

   ```java
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   private static final String SSO_HEADER = "AUTH_USER";

   public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
   public static final String USER = "ROLE_USER";
   public static final String ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";

   @Autowired
   Environment env;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/images/**","/fonts/**","/api/**","/sendRedirect/**","/test/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
               .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
               .and()
               .logout()
               .deleteCookies("remove")
               .invalidateHttpSession(true)
               .logoutUrl("/logout")
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
               .and()
           // Cross-site request forgery is turned off for RESTful API calls with the assumption that
           // authentication will be sufficient protection
           .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**", "/space/{\\d+}/**", "/admin/**");
   }

   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
       throws Exception
   {
       return authenticationManager();
   }

   @Configuration
   protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
           GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

       @Autowired
       Environment env;

       @Override
       public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
           auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("cn={0}")
                   .contextSource(contextSource());
       }

       @Bean
       public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
           LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
           contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
           contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.base"));
           contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.username"));
           contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
           return contextSource;
       }
   }

   }
   ```