# Need code for LDAP Connection/authentication using Spring

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I need a code to connect/authenticate with LDAP server using spring. Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555280/how-to-use-spring-ldap-authentication and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163947/ldap-how-to-authenticate-user-with-connection-details

Answer (score 1):

There is a spring module called **"spring ldap template"**. Documents are [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/introduction.html). A quick guide [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/). LDAP authentication is found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html). There are plenty of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Spring LDAP code samples and examples from the source can be accessed on the following URL:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples